# How to convert RGB int values to string color

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Can anyone tell me how to convert three int vales `r, g, b` into a string color(hexa value) in C#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int red = 255;
int green = 255;
int blue = 255;

string theHexColor = "#" + red.ToString("X2") + green.ToString("X2") + blue.ToString("X2");
```

Comment: Depends on your format: ie ARGB would simply be putting your alpha.ToString("X") in front of red, etc. The big point is that the ToString("X") method will return an integer value in Hex format.

Comment: than in your example its better to write `string color = string.Format("#{0:X}{1:X}{2:X}", r,g,b);`

Comment: Sure, that's equally as valid and more succinct!

Comment: Further information about this method can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y.aspx because I for one never knew about this technique until today :)

Comment: This produces an unparsable string.  Use green=0 for example.  You have to use "X:2"

Comment: That should be `X2` not `X:2`.  Here's the full thing:
`string.Format("${0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", r, g, b)`

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
 string s = Color.FromArgb(255, 143, 143, 143).Name;
```

Comment: I just want to point out that .Name property will not give hex value when Color is not created from Argb. (like Color.Red.Name will return "Red" value )

Comment: Yeah, I know but saikamesh said that he wants to get string from RGB values

Comment: He said he wanted "hexa value".

Comment: The error message I get when I try this is   'System.Windows.Media.Color' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Media.Color' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you should specify that you use wpf or silverligt,`System.Windows.Media.Color` don't have definition for Name, but `System.Drawing.Color` has.

Answer (score 3):

Rgb to Hex:

```
string hexColor = string.Format("0x{0:X8}", Color.FromArgb(r, g, b).ToArgb());
```

Hex to Rgb:

```
int rgbColor = int.Parse("FF", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

Comment: Gives error : 'System.Windows.Media.Color' does not contain a definition for 'ToArgb' and no extension method 'ToArgb' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Media.Color' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

Please find the following extension method:

```
public static class ColorExtensions
{
    public static string ToRgb(this int argb)
    {
        var r = ((argb >> 16) & 0xff);
        var g = ((argb >> 8) & 0xff);
        var b = (argb & 0xff);

        return string.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", r, g, b);
    }
}
```

and here you are the usage:

```
        int colorBlack = 0x000000;
        int colorWhite = 0xffffff;

        Assert.That(colorBlack.ToRgb(), Is.EqualTo("000000"));
        Assert.That(colorWhite.ToRgb(), Is.EqualTo("FFFFFF"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolving this issue for a PowerPoint shape object's Fill.ForeColor.RGB member, I find the RGB values are actually BGR (blue, green, red), so the solution for a C# PowerPoint addin, converting Fill.ForeColor.RGB to a string is:

```
string strColor = "";
var b = ((shpTemp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB >> 16) & 0xff);
var g = ((shpTemp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB >> 8) & 0xff);
var r = (shpTemp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB & 0xff);

strColor = string.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", r, g, b);
```

Answer (score -1):

What I did was the following:

```
    int reducedRed = getRed(long color)/128; // this gives you a number 1 or 0. 
    int reducedGreen = getGreen(long color)/128; // same thing for the green value; 
    int reducedBlue = getBlue(long color)/128; //same thing for blue
    int reducedColor = reducedBlue + reducedGreen*2 + reducedRed*4 ;
    // reduced Color is a number between 0 -7
```

Once you have the reducedColor then perform a switch between 0 to 7.

```
    switch(reducedColor){
       case 0: return "000000";      // corresponds to Black
       case 1: return “0000FF";         // corresponds to Blue
       case 2: return "00FF00";       // corresponds to Green
       case 3: return "00FFFF";        // corresponds to Cyan 
       case 4: return “FF0000";          // corresponds to Red
       case 5: return "FF00FF";       //corresponds to Purple
       case 6: return "FFFF00";     //corresponds to Yellow
       case 7: return  “FFFFFF";       //corresponds to White
    }
```

O